# Kinetic 5.0.2 loading multi image from Json

Tags: json, html, canvas, kineticjs

I would like to build an drawing tool by Kineticjs Framework.
Base on this tutorial:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-load-complex-stage-with-kineticjs/

I generate Json string, and try to recreate object base on the id that I give before. However I release 2 main problem in my code.

1. If there are 2 images which have the same id (in my case: drag and drop twice image from menu to canvas), then when we re drawing it will draw only the last one. The same thing happened in tutorial also.
2. When I try to run this stageReceived.get('#'+ arrMenu[i].id)[0] it is always return undefined, but it works if I type stageReceived.get('#removeMenu')[0]

   ```
    var arrMenu = [];
    function MenuItems(id, type) {
               this.id = id;
               this.type = type;
               this.source = "image/Menu_Icons/" + id + "." + type;
               this.draggable = true;
               return this;
           }

           //declare Object Menu                            
           var removeMenu = new MenuItems("removeMenu", "png");
           var rotate90DegreeMenu = new MenuItems("rotate90DegreeMenu", "jpg");
           var rotate180DegreeMenu = new MenuItems("rotate180DegreeMenu", "png");

           arrMenu.push(removeMenu);
           arrMenu.push(rotate90DegreeMenu);
           arrMenu.push(rotate180DegreeMenu);
   ```

   // user press send button to generate and drawing stage in another div

   ```
           $('#send').click(function() {
               //declare json string 
               var json = stage.toJSON();
               console.log(json);
               // prepare stage 
               var stageReceived = Kinetic.Node.create(json, 'divMilldeRight');
               var imageObj = new Image();
               for (var i = 0; i < arrMenu.length; i++) {
                   var idImage = '#';
                   idImage = idImage + arrMenu[i].id;

                   imageObj.onload = function() {
                       printConsole("onload function", idImage);
                       if (stageReceived.get(idImage)[0].image(imageObj)) {
                           stageReceived.draw();
                       }

                   };
                   imageObj.src = arrMenu[i].source;
               }
            });
   ```

Any help is appreciate a lot :) thanks in advance.

Credit for @Elsa. Set the same different id for the same image everytime it is insert, but giving the same name. find array of images by .find('.name') do loop and .get('#id'). problem solved. Hope it help sb has same trouble.

```
            var shapes = stage.find('.image');//get the array of image
            // doing loop for every shape
            shapes.each(function(shape){
                console.log(shape.attrs.id); // get the different id of each shape
                stage.get('#'+shape.attrs.id)[0].image(imageObj); // set it for image
            });
            imageObj.src = source;
            stage.draw();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to never set the same id to different nodes. The main concept of the id is to define **unique** nodes. You'd better use the `name` attribute if you want to call different images.

You can then do this

```
stageReceived.get('.'+ thename)[0]; //or .find
```